# Powershell Web Server two or more actions on a page

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

By using some instructions from the [GIT Hub URL](https://github.com/SevenWishes/TechNet-Gallery/tree/master/Powershell%20Webserver) and my own work I created a Powershell Web Server. But now I stopped at, how to store two or more data in different variables on one page.
For example in this scenario, I need to provide a User Name and Manager Name, for command New-AdUser. I will have much more of the data than these two, but let's leave it for now.

This is how the website looks like for now:

[image]

After executing this script I am receiving:

```
?CreateName=John+Doe&CreateManager=John+Lenon&CreateButton=create
```

With no possibilities to split the variable in two, both names are in the same variable, I am able to clear unnecessary data by using -replace, but as I said I need to split them into two variables $ to have it work correctly.

As you see by the code below I used two GET methods on a page to enter different variables.

```
!HEADERLINE
<p>
<h2> This is a Header </h2>
<h3>some text in here</h3>
<pre>!RESULT</pre>
<form method="GET" action="/">
<b>User Name</b></br><input type="text" maxlength=255 size=50 name="CreateName" value=''>
</br><form method="GET" action="/">
<b>Manager Name</b></br><input type="text" maxlength=255 size=50 name="CreateManager" value=''>
</br>
</br><input type="submit" name="CreateButton" value="create" >
</form>
</p>
```

This is the part of the code from switch GET, currently, it doing nothing than showing me the output, so be aware of that.

```
switch ($RECEIVED)
    {
        "GET /"
        {   # execute command
            # retrieve GET query string
            $CreateUserName = ''
            $CreateUserName = [URI]::UnescapeDataString(($REQUEST.Url.Query))

            $RESULT =  $CreateUserName 2> $NULL | Out-String
```

But what I wanted is to receive:

```
$CreateName = 'John Doe'
$CreateManager = 'John Lenon'
```

The data from the HTML forms stored in, to insert to
`New-ADUser -Name $CreateName -Manager $CreateManager`

This is the first time when I writing scripts on a web server, but I have a lot of completed scripts in Powershell. I hope there are other options than running other ps1 scripts directly from the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By getting access to .Net Framework class `HttpUtility` you can easily parse the query string.

```ps
$query = '?CreateName=John+Doe&CreateManager=John+Lenon&CreateButton=create'
$queryString = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString($query)
$createName = $queryString['CreateName']
Write-Host $createName
```

Displays

> John Doe

Not sure if there is a more Powershell style solution out there but this should work. Also take a look on `$queryString.AllKeys`. It can be useful to process many fields in a loop.

Also if you receive full url you can do: `$uri = New-Object System.Uri 'http://example.com?CreateName=John+Doe` and then retrieve the query part of the url `$uri.Query`. So to get query string object it is: `$queryString = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString($uri.Query)`

Comment: Alright, Somehow I was able to add John Doe to a Form "CreateName", so we have a 50% success here, I am still struggling with other form to apply to the next variable. If I  found the solution I will post it here.
I had to change $query = '$CreateUserName'

Comment: Thanks Lad, your response was 100% accurate, I did some changes and now it is worked. 
I did another line with $createName = $queryString['CreateName'] but assigned it to a CreateManager and it is reading now second form. I owe you a virtual beer.